# Firebase HTTP Cloud Function timeout

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to copy exactly the same style as the guy in this video does:

https://youtu.be/7IkUgCLr5oA?t=259

[image]

Here's my version (mine is JS, his is TS):

```
exports.upload = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {});
        const pr = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
            form = formidable()
            form.parse(req, (err,fields,files) => {
                resolve(files.toString())
            });
        });
        pr.then(data=>res.send(data));
    });
});
```

My code just lags until the response times out. Any ideas why? I've tried all sorts of other ways, without using the Promise, but nothing works.

Comment: BTW, changing it to `resolve('asdasd')`, doesn't help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Screenshot is from the video.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how the video related with your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What happens if you catch errors: `pr.then(data=>res.send(data)).catch(error => {console.log(error); });`. You should see the output in the Firebase console.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Nothing, no errors logged.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use `formidable-serverless`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-serverless